# How to send concurrent request in PHP using AWS Lambda?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

How to perform this action on AWS Lambda? with PHP Code?

**Note:** *I have successfully integrated PHP with custom run time environment and I can run PHP code as well as connect the RDS successfully.*

What I am looking for is.

Let's say there are 1000 users in an array and want to add log in database.

In normal PHP code the pointer behavior will be like below.

in `for` loop the pointer will pick up the `USER ID 1` and add row in database table and assume it will take approximate half sec for one user and for 1000 users it will be 500 seconds. This means the process will be running for 500 secs, but what I actually wants to do is.

Make a loop which simply ping the lambda url `aws.lambda.url/dev/?id=1` with id as mentioned and lambda perform the database insertion. No matter how much time lambda will take but the script execution will be completed in few seconds after ping to URL.

[Another case]

How can I make fire and forgot request for PHP? In above case, I just wanted to insert log in database no matter what is the response. I don't care about response at that will be always true.

Hope I am clear. if not just let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure I understand, but you could put your update jobs to sqs in batches (10 at a time) and let sqs->lambda integration do the rest. To send 1000 jobs, you need 100 requests to sqs. Or use kinesis with batches of 500 records, and just do two requests to kinesis.

Comment: Any tutorial available?